# Vietnamese Spelling Irregularities

Tags: phonology, orthography, vietnamese

### The Case with Mandarin

I’m quite familiar with Chinese Pinyin, and I know it has some irregularities with how it represents it phonemes:

1. The use of `<y>`/`<w>`/`<yu>` when `<i>`/`<u>`/`<ü>` are part of a syllable with a null initial
2. The elimination of the diaeresis when `<ü>` is preceded by `<q>`/`<j>`/`<x>`
3. Representing the `/jəu/` coda with `<you>`/`-<iu>` but `/jau/` with `<yao>`/`-<iao>`
4. Representing the `/wəi/` coda with `<wei>`/`-<ui>` but `/wai/` with `<wai>`/`-<uai>`
5. Representing the `/uə/` coda as just `<o>` after `<p>`/`<b>`/`<f>`/`<m>`, but `<uo>` elsewhere

(Rules 3 and 4 are, surprisingly, among some of the most regular of irregulars since there are a few more rules that follow the pattern of dropping the letter representing `/ə/`.)

---

### What About Vietnamese?

What are some irregular ways Vietnamese represents its phonemes? My understanding of Vietnamese phonotactics is limited, and the spelling rules seem to carry a lot of baggage from Latin, Portuguese, and Italian.

Some of what I figured out from Wikipedia’s pages on [Vietnamese phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vietnamese_phonology&oldid=783915391) and the [alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vietnamese_alphabet&oldid=782718424):

1. `/k/` is represented by `<c>`/`<k>`/`<q>` with `<k>` appearing before `<i>`/`<y>`/`<e>`/`<ê>`, `<qu>` representing `/kw/`, and `<c>` in all other cases.
2. `/ɣ/` is represented by `<g>`/`<gh>` with `<gh>` appearing before `<i>`/`<e>`/`<ê>`, and `<g>` in all other cases.
3. `<ă>` is represented by just `<a>` before an offglide (`<y>`/`<u>`) or palatal consonant coda (`<ch>`/`<nh>`).
4. When not followed by a coda, `<iê>`/`<yê>` is written `<ia>`/`<ya>`.
5. When not followed by a coda, `<ươ>` is written `<ưa>`.
6. When not followed by a coda, `<uô>` is written `<ua>`.
7. Tone marks over the `<i>` in the initial sequence `<gi>` distinguishes `<gi>`+`<a>` from `<gi>`+`<ia>`. When the syllable has no tones, it’s ambiguous!

**Are there any more rules?**

Comment: @sumelic Good catch! I had Classical Greek with the aspirated/voiceless/voiced series floating around in my head for some reason. Funny that Vietnamese had the same thing and many of them weakened to fricatives like in modern Greek.

Comment: Vietnamese orthography is virtually unchanged since the Dictionarium of Alexandre de Rhodes in the 17th century. Your points 1 and 2 are carry-overs from Portuguese orthography. Points 3, 4, 5, 6 presumably reflect sound shifts in (Hanoi) Vietnamese since the 17th century. Point 7 is merely an inconsistency in the system.

Comment: @fdb Looking at the pattern, I believe that `<a>` in cases 4–6 represent a sort of “catch-all”/“meh” vowel or schwa. I haven’t looked too deeply into Vietnamese phonology yet, but it could be the case that the underlying phoneme is actually a schwa with different phonetic realizations in different contexts. In case 3, `<y>` and `<u>` contrast with `<i>` and `<o>` after `<a>`, so it seems the `<i>` and `<o>` serves a double purpose of marking the preceding `<a>` as long (`<a>`) rather than short (`<ă>`). As for `<gi>`, it’s become apparent to me that it actually represented `/gi/` historically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much reading, I figured that I pretty much answered my question in the question itself. There is one more rule, however!

Vietnamese velar codas undergo labialization after back vowels (`<o>`/`<ô>`/`<u>`):

> ```
> Original form   → Labio-velarized form
> 1. xong /sɔŋ˧/  → [sɔŋm˧]
> 2. trong /cɔŋ˧/ → [cɔŋm˧]
> 3. múc /muk˧˥/  → [mukp˧˥]
> 4. công /koŋ˧/  → [koŋm˧]
> ```
>
> Table 5.6: Examples of the labio-velarization rule

This does not apply to `/uə/` (`<uô>`):

> *suông* /suoŋ˧/ "flow smoothly", not affected by the Labio-velarization rule

In words where labialization is not desired for `<o>`/`<ô>`, the vowel is doubled:

> - The vowel /ɔ/ is written *oo* before *c* or *ng* (since *o* in that position represents /aw/): /ʔɔk/ = *oóc* 'organ (musical)'; /kiŋ kɔŋ/ = *kính coong*. This generally only occurs in recent loanwords or when representing dialectal pronunciation.
> - Similarly, the vowel /o/ is written *ôô* before *c* or *ng*: /ʔoŋ/ = *[ôông](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%B4%C3%B4ng)* ([Nghệ An](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngh%E1%BB%87_An)/[Hà Tĩnh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A0_T%C4%A9nh) variant of *ông* /ʔəwŋ/). But unlike *oo* being frequently used in onomatopoeia, [transcriptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_transcription) from other languages and words "borrowed" from Nghệ An/Hà Tĩnh dialects (such as *[voọc](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vo%E1%BB%8Dc)*), *ôô* seems to be used solely to convey the feel of the Nghệ An/Hà Tĩnh accents. In transcriptions, *ô* is preferred (e.g. *các-tông* 'cardboard', *ắc-coóc-đê-ông* 'accordion').

---

And here are the rules I mentioned [before](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/23190/16696):

> 1. `/k/` is represented by `<c>`/`<k>`/`<q>` with `<k>` appearing before `<i>`/`<y>`/`<e>`/`<ê>`, `<qu>` representing `/kw/`, and `<c>`
>      in all other cases.
> 2. `/ɣ/` is represented by `<g>`/`<gh>` with `<gh>` appearing before `<i>`/`<e>`/`<ê>`, and `<g>` in all other cases.
> 3. `<ă>` is represented by just `<a>` before an offglide (`<y>`/`<u>`) or palatal consonant coda (`<ch>`/`<nh>`).
> 4. When not followed by a coda, `<iê>`/`<yê>` is written `<ia>`/`<ya>`.
> 5. When not followed by a coda, `<ươ>` is written `<ưa>`.
> 6. When not followed by a coda, `<uô>` is written `<ua>`.
> 7. Tone marks over the `<i>` in the initial sequence `<gi>` distinguishes `<gi>`+`<a>` from `<gi>`+`<ia>`. When the syllable has
>      no tones, it’s ambiguous!

---

### Sources

1. Emerich, Giang Huong, "The Vietnamese Vowel System" (2012). Publicly Accessible Penn Dissertations. 632. http://repository.upenn.edu/edissertations/632
2. André-Georges Haudricourt. The origin of the peculiarities of the Vietnamese alphabet. Mon-Khmer Studies, 2010, 39, pp.89-104. <[halshs-00918824v2](https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00918824v2)>
3. Vietnamese alphabet. (2017, May 28). In *Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia*. Retrieved 01:05, June 18, 2017, from https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Vietnamese_alphabet&oldid=782718424